# Is there any C macro that wraps a function?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to do something like what I was willing to do with this syntax:

```
#define WRAP_MY_FUNCTION(x){Y} void x(int integer){printf("begin\n"); Y ; printf("end\n");}
```

So I can have this

```
WRAP_MY_FUNCTION(Foo){printf("hello world\n");}
```

which is equivalent to

```
void Foo(int integer)
{
    printf("begin\n");
    printf("hello world\n");
    printf("end\n");
}
```

to output

```
begin
hello world
end
```

Note: I'd prefer to have function code in brackets so the end-user understands this is a code block.

Comment: It's not possible with the syntax you have. Is there a reason you are not doing `#define WRAP_MY_FUNCTION(x, Y) ...` instead?

Comment: because i would like to have brackets so end-user understands its a function block, but anyway, If it's not possible (X,Y) might be ok

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in another parameter to the macro to define your print statement.

Something like this:

```
#define WRAP_MY_FUNCTION(x, Y) void x(int integer){printf("begin\n"); Y; printf("end\n");}

WRAP_MY_FUNCTION(Foo, printf("hello world\n"))
```

If you'd like to make it more clear to the end user that this is a code block and, as rici pointed out, adding a Variadic macro to fix unprotected commas that might be in your source, you could rewrite your definition to be:

```
#define WRAP_MY_FUNCTION(x, ...)\
    void x(int integer)         \
    {                           \
        printf("begin\n");      \
        __VA_ARGS__             \
        printf("end\n");        \
    }                           \
```

Comment: Better to write that as a variadic macro. Otherwise, unprotected commas in `Y` will cause problems.

Comment: In general, yes, but I believe in this case a variadic macro wouldn't solve the underlying problem. Any unprotected comma in Y won't be intended as a parameter but as part of the source. In that case the better solution would be to alias the offending parameter or parenthesize it.

Comment: As a concrete example, `WRAP(foo, if (arg > 2) { int a=1, b=2; ... })`. The comma is unprotected and will cause a syntax error, `WRAP` has too many arguments. If you used `#define WRAP(x, ...) void x(int arg) { before(); __VA_ARGS__ after(); }`, then the problem vanishes.